# Matlab fit with function returning vector with all the y(x_i) values

Tags: matlab, vector, data-fitting

I am working on something and I haven't found any solution, maybe I didn't know how to correctly search for it...

I have two arrays of experimental data (x and y). x is a list of certain energies (512 values from 0 to 100 kev) and I want to fit them to a function which returns a vector of values of y for every x in the list (the energies are always the same, 512 certain values). This is because my function model contains several matrix and other functions.
So, I can't evaluate my function as f(x,a,b,c...) (with a,b,c the parameters to fit) and expect a single scalar, but I have to evaluate f(a,b,c...), and it returns a vector of y(x1),y(x2)...

Now, I want to fit my data to my model. But lsqcurvefit needs a function of the form f(x), I suppose that it evaluates every f(x). I could write my function so that every time it is called it evaluates the vector result, and then returns y for the given x, but it would be quite inefficient... And I'm sure there must be another way.

Any idea?

Comment: Very unclear and undetailed model..........

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do an fminsearch on the sum of square errors? It is best to put all fitting parameters into one vector. Here I call it `p`.

```
f = @(x,p) (p(3)+p(1)*x.^p(2)).^(1/p(4); %example function with four free parameters
sqerr = @(x,y,p) sum((y-f(x,p)).^2); %sum of squared errors
p = [1,1,1,1]; %four starting conditions
p = fminsearch(@(p) sqerr(x,y,p),p); %fit
```

Then you can find your y(x_i) values by calling the function with the fitted paramters

```
f(x,p)
```